# Oracle comparing day to second interval to an integer

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, oracle12c, intervals

I am wondering what is going on under the hood of oracle when I am trying to compare day to second interval with a integer.

Example below.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    v_date1 TIMESTAMP := current_timestamp ;
    v_date2 TIMESTAMP := current_timestamp - 150;
BEGIN
    -- Wrong way. But what is happening here?
    IF v_date1 - v_date2 < 2 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES - why?');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO');
    END IF;
    -- Correct way
    IF v_date1 < v_date2 + 2 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO - works as expected');
    END IF;
    -- Another correct way
    IF v_date1 - v_date2 < INTERVAL '2' DAY THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO - works as expected as well');
    END IF;
END;
```

Can somebody explain to me why first IF is evaluated to true?

Comment: Interesting. In SQL, a condition  like `WHERE INTERVAL '1' MINUTE < 2` fails whereas `IF INTERVAL '1' MINUTE < 2 ` in PL/SQL does not throw error. Same behaviour even in 18c : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c298d9a71d0b25b68a6c5483e66d6e33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing seems to be a bug, or at least undocumented behaviour. So unfortunately I think you'd need to raise a service request with Oracle to get an explanation. Only they can peer under the hood and see if it's doing what they expect or is something they hadn't thought of.

---

Breaking down some of the steps, not just for your specific question:

```
v_date1 TIMESTAMP := current_timestamp ;
```

casts `current_timestamp`, which is is the time in your session time zone, to a plain timestamp - losing the time zone information.

```
v_date2 TIMESTAMP := current_timestamp - 150;
```

has two steps; `current_timestamp - 150` gives you a date, losing the fractional seconds *and* time zone information, and then casts that back to a timestamp. It would be better to use `- interval '150' day`, but I realise you're just setting up some dummy data here.

```
IF v_date1 - v_date2 < 2 THEN
```

is also multiple stages: `v_date1 - v_date2` gives you an interval, e.g. `+150 00:00:00.975444`. (Notice that is isn't exactly 150 days, partly because of the small elapsed time between the two `current_dtimestamp` calls, but much larger than you'd expect from just that difference - because of the precision loss from the earlier bounce through the date data type.)

Then the comparison itself is where it gets interesting. It looks like an implicit data conversion is happening, but you're trying to compare an interval with a number, and there is no implicit conversion that allows that; and in plain SQL trying to do the same comparison errors:

```
select case when current_timestamp - (current_timestamp - 150) < 2 then 'yes' else 'no' end from dual;

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER
```

So it appears PL/SQL is doing some other implicit conversion, but it isn't obvious what, and it doesn't seem to be documented or mentioned on MoS. It doesn't appear to be a string comparison, or raw, or conversion of that 2 to either interval type, or conversion of the interval to a number, or the interval or either timestamp in the calculation to dates...

There doesn't seem to be any numeric value that makes that comparison return false - whether the left-hand side is a calculation (which could potentially be being rewritten to something more like your second version) or fixed interval variable. That makes it seem more like a bug than intentional.

One last thing from your original code:

```
-- Correct way
IF v_date1 < v_date2 + 2 THEN
```

This isn't really quite correct either, though it might seem picky; `v_date + 2` gives you a date rather than a timestamp, so if you hadn't already lost the fractional seconds precision earlier (with the - 150) then you would at this point. And now you're comparing a timestamp with a date, which involves more implicit conversion. You could change the numeric 2 to a 2-day interval, but that would be logically the same as your final (correct) comparison.

Comment: I also tried `to_number(v_date1 - v_date2)` and `CAST(2 AS INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND)` but they are both failing, even in PL/SQL IF-Statement. In deed very mysterious.

Comment: "The difference is not exactly 150 days" not only due to losing the fractional seconds, it is also due to assigning CURRENT_TIMESTAMP at different times. It doesn't work like SQL, where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the same for all calls within a single query. Instead, each call fetches a new value. A quick and trivial test showed a difference of 0.000006 seconds on my system, between two successive calls in the same anonymous block.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time on this issue. You are not writing anything helpfull for answering my question here really, but the post is very interesting, and I do not think there will be a better answer provided. ;)

Comment: No, agreed *8-) The first paragraph is the only bit that's at all helpful, and barely... I started writing the rest while assuming I'd figure it out, and then thought I might as well post it anyway to save other people repeating what I'd done.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not a bug, but wrong source code.

You should treat intervals as INTERVAL

```
DECLARE
    v_date1 TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
    v_date2 TIMESTAMP := v_date1 - INTERVAL '150' DAY;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_date1 - v_date2);
    -- Right way.
    IF v_date1 - v_date2 < INTERVAL '2' DAY THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES - why?');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO');
    END IF;
    -- Right way
    IF v_date1 < v_date2 + INTERVAL '2' DAY THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO - works as expected');
    END IF;
    -- Right correct way
    IF v_date1 - v_date2 < INTERVAL '2' DAY THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YES');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO - works as expected as well');
    END IF;
END;

+000000150 00:00:00.000000000
NO
NO - works as expected
NO - works as expected as well
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, I know that I should treat intervals as INTERVAL. My question was what is going under the hood in oracle when I am using integer instead. ;)

Comment: Great, ..just wanted to point out the right way to solve the use case. Cheers!